# Tmux new named session exited

Tags: tmux

I can't start a new named tmux session.
Below shows what gets printed. Note the `0;95;c` weird statement.

```
> tmux new test
[exited]
> 0;95;c
```

I can, however start a un-named session and rename it in tmux.

I used to be able to start with a named session. Have not been using it for quite sometime, and I'm not sure what has been done to the system that might have some implications.

How can I fix this?
How do I view the debug log or something?

Ubuntu10.04
Tmux 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tmux interprets `test` as a shell command, executes it and terminates afterwards.

To create a session named *test*, use `tmux new-session -s test` or `tmux new -s test`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I forgot about the -s :)